# Consulta de MySQL no muestra datos

Tags: c#, windows-forms, mysql-workbench

Alguien que me ayude, estoy haciendo una consulta en MySQL con C#, pero no me muestra ningun dato, esta es la consulta que estoy haciendo:

```
public DataTable Espera(String Programa, String FI, String FF)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String query = @"SELECT IL.Cliente, CA.Programa, IL.Estilo,
                                IL.Color, SUM(IL.Total) AS Pares, 
                                CA.Material, CA.Departamento,
                                CA.Fecha_Pago AS Fecha_Pedido 
                         FROM  galaxyfx_produccion.compras_ange AS CA INNER 
                            JOIN galaxyfx_produccion.infolote AS IL 
                            ON CA.Programa = IL.Programa 
                         WHERE (CA.Programa LIKE '%"+ Programa + @"%') 
                         AND (CA.Estado = 'En Espera') 
                         AND (CA.Fecha_Pago BETWEEN '"+ FI 
                              +"' AND '"+ FF + @"') 
                         GROUP BY CA.Material, CA.Programa, 
                                  CA.Departamento, CA.Fecha_Pago";

        dt = daccess.select(query);
        return dt;
    }
```

Ya le modificado varias veces, pero no queda, además de que si le quito lo del rango de fechas, funciona normalmente.

Comment: sera un problema con las fechas entonces? necesitariamos ver los datos, los tipos de datos, y como es el query que tratas de ejecutar

Comment: Pero el query, ya lo puse, el tipo de dato de las fechas es date, y la fecha la mando en de esta forma: "yyyy/MM/dd" para que se paresca como esta guardada en la base de datos

Comment: no es cuestion que se parezca, el formato con el que mandas es importante, y por query me refiero al query resuelto...

Comment: y en la base de datos, vos estas seguro que esta guardado de esa forma?? y no como dia/mes/año?

Comment: no, ya me di cuenta de mi error, no le me estaba aceptando el formato adecuado con el datetimepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EL problema es este, no puedes comparar las fechas así, **NUNCA**. porque ? porque la representaciónn de la fecha depende de cada cultura/ configuración regional.
así que primero debes asegurarte de estar usando el mismo formato de fecha en la BD y en los string que recibes como parámetro.

digamos que los valores que recibes como parámetro sean formato dd/mm/yyyy en ese caso los campos de la bd que son DATE debes convertirlos a un string con ese formato.

Piensa en ello como "Una cosa eres tu y otra como te vistes" un tipo date tiene mucha información y la puedes mostrar de diferentes maneras, así que para asegurarte de hacer una buena comparación debes mostrarlo en la forma que necesitas, en este caso 'dd/mm/yyyy'

Lo malo es que cada BD lo hace de manera diferente, así que debes lidiar con eso si es ue sigues usando la proximación que escogiste en tu codigo, que debo decir que no es la mejor.

Par mysql, si quieres mostrar el string como dd/mm/yyyy debes usar algo como esto para mostrar la fecha de la BD de una forma diferente.  `DATE_FORMAT(CA.Fecha_Pago, "%d/%m/%Y")`

```
 AND ( DATE_FORMAT(CA.Fecha_Pago, "%d/%m/%Y") BETWEEN '"+ FI +"' AND '"+ FF + @"')
```

A parte de eso hay muchas otras cosas mal, partiendo del hecho de que el código esta tremendamente inseguro.

Trata de usar parameter binding como se muestra en este ejemplo, si pasas a este esquema todas las conversiones las puedes hacer de manera uniforme en C# sin imporar que motor de DB uses.

```
   static void CountCourses(String connectionString, Int32 year) {  
      String commandText = "Select Count([CourseID]) FROM [MySchool].[dbo].[Course] Where Year=@Year";  
      SqlParameter parameterYear = new SqlParameter("@Year", SqlDbType.Int);  
      parameterYear.Value = year;  

      Object oValue = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(connectionString, commandText, CommandType.Text, parameterYear);  
      Int32 count;  
      if (Int32.TryParse(oValue.ToString(), out count))  
         Console.WriteLine("There {0} {1} course{2} in {3}.", count > 1 ? "are" : "is", count, count > 1 ? "s" : null, year);  
   }
```

Y aún mucho más importante aléjate de eso y trata de usar mejor entity framework y LinQ

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html#connector-net-ef6-codefirst

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-databinding-linq-entities.html

Comment: De hecho tienes razon, me estaba equivocando porque no mandaba el formato correcto de la fecha, pero me queda una duda, ¿Por qué esta mal la forma en que lo hago? y ¿Por qué es inseguro el codigo que muestro?, y lo que me comentas de como mejorarlo, se puede implementar con la forma en que programo, programo en MVC

Comment: Porque el código abre una vulnerabilidad en tu sitio web por medio de inyección de SQL.Que es un ataque muy sencillo que puede acabar tu plataforma por completo. Mira este video ilustrativo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mSImYK3824

Comment: Lectura obligatoria en temas de seguridad en el desarrollo de sistemas web: https://www.owasp.org

Comment: Otro ejemplo valioso https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/how-sql-injection-can-be-possible-in-asp-net-websites/

Comment: no es un sistema web, es para una aplicacion de escritorio

Comment: también se puede inyectar SQL en sistemas de escritorio... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495753/do-sql-injection-works-in-winforms

Comment: ok, muchas gracias por las sugerencias, tratare de implementar esto a la forma como programo